# Make a class property type to be of certain type on initiation

Tags: dart

I have these two classes, I need the `ParsedResponse.data` property to take in different types on initiation. Currently it is fixed to taking to `Status` class. Is there a way to do this other than making `ParsedResponse.data` of a type `dynamic`?

```
class ParsedResponse {
  int? status;
  String? message;
  Status data;

  ParsedResponse({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory ParsedResponse.fromResponse(Response<dynamic> res) => ParsedResponse(
        status: res.statusCode,
        message: res.statusMessage,
        data: Status.fromJson(res.data),
      );
}

class Status {
  int? otp;
  late DateTime expiresIn;
  late bool isRegistered;

  Status({
    this.otp,
    required this.expiresIn,
    required this.isRegistered,
  });

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Status(
      otp: json['otp'],
      isRegistered: json['is_registered'],
      expiresIn: DateTime.parse(json['expires_in']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a type argument for the class might be best:

```
class ParsedResponse<T> {
  int? status;
  String? message;
  T data;

  ParsedResponse({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory ParsedResponse.fromResponse(Response<dynamic> res) =>
      ParsedResponse(
          status: res.statusCode,
          message: res.statusMessage,
          data: Status.fromJson(res.data));
}
```

The problem with the above code is the following:

```
data: Status.fromJson(res.data));
```

if data can be anything, the above will not work, I propose the following:

```
  factory ParsedResponse.fromResponse(
    Response<dynamic> res, {
    required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) dataParser,
  }) =>
   ParsedResponse(
          status: res.statusCode,
          message: res.statusMessage,
          data: dataParser(res.data));
```

that way, when you want to make parsed response with status data:

```
final parsedResponse = ParsedResponse<Status>.fromResponse(
    response, 
    dataParser: (map) => Status.fromJson(map));
```

and say you want to make a parsed response where data is an int 1.

```
final parsedResponse = ParsedResponse<int>.fromResponse(response, (_) => 1);
```